# Where is the file Elite Dangerous stores the controls?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'd like to easily backup my controls in Elite: Dangerous. Does anyone know where the controls are stored, or a way to find out? Thanks!

Comment: I don't really play the game but it would be in a file like C:\program files\elite dangerous\cfg\elite.cfg or similar cfg file so be sure to check your install directory and copy over any cfg file.

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked through all kinds of .cfg and .xml files and can't find where the settings are stored. So I was wondering if someone else had found them by now. :)

Answer (score 14):

I have found them here for the Beta 1.02:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Frontier Developments\Elite Dangerous\Options\Bindings\

There are 2 files of interest: "Custom.binds" and "StartPreset.start"

Answer (score 8):

If you copy the `Custom.binds` file to `MyName.binds` (or something) it will appear in the drop-down menu for you to choose from.

Comment: I just tried this in 1.4 and you will have to do one more step. In the file you will need to change the value of PresetName in the root tag of the XML to what you want to show in the drop down.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found them! I don't know if they added them since the beta came out, or what. But It looks like custom bindings are saved in a file here: \Users\USER\Local\Frontier Developments\Elite Dangerous\Options\Bindings

Answer (score 5):

On the Mac they are stored in : `~/Library/Application Support/Frontier Developments/Elite Dangerous/Options/Bindings`

Where `~/` is your user folder `/Users/<your_user_name>/Library/Application Supp...`

Answer (score 2):

Found it a bit silly i couldnt just add comments for clarification but can provide a new answer. Regardless, just to update / concur:

**Elite Dangerous Horizons V2018.12.17.190809**

Location:

> C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Local\Frontier Developments\Elite
>   Dangerous\Options\Bindings\

AS stated previously;
"There are 2 files of interest: "**Custom.binds**" and "**StartPreset.start**""
But you dont need to do anything with the startpreset file, when in-game that file will update to whatever you last 'loaded'.

When COPYING to make additional config profiles, as stated in a comment by GERT. You need to edit the **PRESETNAME** inside the file as well as the actual file name.

What i noticed was that the baseline Custom.binds file didnt have that option but i had an extra file called **custom.3.0.binds** which did have a preset.

So copy that one, edit the file name and preset inside the file, save and reload your game.

I did all this in testing setup for a 3D mouse (3Dconnexion) for very fine controls esp for docking [which i was only able to get working by using ControlMyJoystick as by default this does not work well at all].

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Ubuntu) I found them under:

```
steamapps/compatdata/359320/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/AppData/Local/Frontier Developments/Elite Dangerous/Options/Bindings
```

The location of steamapps depends on your steam library location.